# Installation of LaTeX package: fetch external resources

Tags: packages, package-writing

I am writing a LaTeX class and aim to bundle it as `.dtx`. My problem is that the class uses graphics that are available for download on the internet, but the license doesn't allow me to spread them along with my class.

So my question is: Is there a preferred way to bundle a class so that it fetches external resources on installation (using `curl` / `wget` / whatever)? Is there a way to make this cross-platform? Currently I'm using a Makefile, but this isn't a solution for Windows users.

Comment: Is requiring LuaTeX to typeset the docs an option? Lua can do this without external programs, and I assume this wouldn't break the operation of the package itself.

Comment: I don't know anything about LuaTeX, typesetting the docs is currently done with XeLaTeX. Can I switch between these?

Comment: Ltiitle hint: you can adress people by adding an `@` sign before their name. @flyx You can do most of the stuff with LuaTeX as well, and much more things are possible with Lua- tahn with XeLaTeX. Why are you using XeLaTeX right now?

Comment: @Johannes_B: I'm using XeLaTeX because of fontspec and unicode support. I *could* switch to LuaTeX, but I'm not sure much work it is to port my XeLaTeX sources.

Comment: LuaTeX can do that as well. Just try it out, should work out of the box. Caveat: LuaTeX is a bit slower.

Comment: @JosephWright Do you have the Lua code at hand or can ping somebody you are sure can answer the question? I can't from the top of my head.